# MySQL Trigger UPDATE not triggering

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm not getting the right output from MySQL UPDATE Triggers. I'm using MySQL 5.5.30. My problem is based on this MySQL Triggers tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/. I'll summarise the scenario and you can try this out on the MySQL client.

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` text,
    `content` text,
    `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ix_deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Blog posts';

CREATE TABLE `audit` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `blog_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `changetype` enum('NEW','EDIT','DELETE','OTHER') NOT NULL,
    `changetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ix_blog_id` (`blog_id`),
    KEY `ix_changetype` (`changetype`),
    KEY `ix_changetime` (`changetime`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_audit_blog_id` FOREIGN KEY (`blog_id`) REFERENCES `blog` (`id`) ON      DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `blog_after_update` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `blog` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.deleted THEN
            SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'EDIT';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);   
     END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger 'blog_after_update' in the example above works. The result of the trigger should result in 'EDIT' being inserted into a row in the audit table. This works because another column other than the 'deleted' column gets updated.

However I changed the trigger in the tutorial slightly to reproduce the TRIGGER I was after, as described below:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `blog_after_update` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `blog` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.content THEN
            SET @changetype = 'EDIT';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'OTHER';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);   
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

According to my findings, this still results in the ELSE block being executed. I am expecting the IF block i.e. 'SET @changetype = 'EDIT';' to execute.

Is anyone able to suggest why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to check if some content is changed then set the change type as edit and you can do by comparing new value with old value. Something as

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `blog_after_update` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `blog` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.content <> old.content THEN
            SET @changetype = 'EDIT';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'OTHER';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);   
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this: NEW.content <> old.content worked rather than NEW.content